# Scribe with QTIWorks

Tags: java, scribe

I'm using scribe to connect with [QTIWorks](https://webapps.ph.ed.ac.uk/qtiworks/)

I found this question [How to create a oAuth request using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725802/how-to-create-a-oauth-request-using-java)

I write this QTIWorks class

```
package testscribe;

import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;

public class QTIWorks extends DefaultApi10a {

@Override
public Verb getRequestTokenVerb()
{
  return Verb.GET;
}

@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    return "https://webapps.ph.ed.ac.uk/qtiworks-dev2/lti/domainlaunch";
}

@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    return "none";
}

/*@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken) {
    return "none";*/

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token token) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

and this is Main class

```
package testscribe;

import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(QTIWorks.class).apiKey("gmail.com/zeina.helwani").apiSecret("v6wPuluQXPwX3vva71ZpR7i1fsbGPaT6")
        .scope("API.Public").build();

Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,"https://webapps.ph.ed.ac.uk/qtiworks-dev2/lti/domainlaunch");
service.signRequest(requestToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
System.out.println(response.getBody());


}

}
```

but it is give me this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>QTIWorks - Method Not Allowed (HTTP Error 405)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic|Ubuntu:500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/qtiworks-dev2/lib/960/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/qtiworks-dev2/lib/960/text.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/qtiworks-dev2/lib/fluid960gs/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/qtiworks-dev2/includes/qtiworks.css?v=1.0-SNAPSHOT">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/qtiworks-dev2/includes/qtiworks.js?v=1.0-SNAPSHOT"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/qtiworks-dev2/lib/html5shiv.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body class="page">
    <div class="container_12">
      <header class="pageHeader">



            <h1><a href="/qtiworks-dev2/">QTIWorks</a></h1>


      </header>


      <h2>Method Not Allowed (HTTP Error 405)</h2>

  <p>You used an HTTP method which is not allowed here.</p><h3>Further Details</h3>
  <strong>Message:</strong> Request method &#039;GET&#039; not supported<br>
  <strong>Status Code:</strong> 405<br>
  <strong>Request URI:</strong> /qtiworks-dev2/lti/domainlaunch<br>

      <div class="clear"></div>
      <footer>
        <div class="logos">
          <a href="http://www.jisc.ac.uk"><img src="/qtiworks-dev2/includes/images/jisc75.png" width="75" height="50" alt="JISC Logo" /></a>
          <a href="http://www.ed.ac.uk"><img src="/qtiworks-dev2/includes/images/uoe.png" width="60" height="60" alt="University of Edinburgh Logo" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
          <p>
            QTIWorks 1.0-SNAPSHOT &#x2012; <a href="/qtiworks-dev2/release-notes.jsp">Release notes</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            Copyright &#xa9; Thu Apr 09 13:16:35 BST 2015
            <a href="http://www.ph.ed.ac.uk">The School of Physics and Astronomy</a>,
            <a href="http://www.ed.ac.uk">The University of Edinburgh</a>.
          </p>
          <p>
            Contact: <a href="mailto:david.mckain@ed.ac.uk">David McKain</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            The University of Edinburgh is a charitable body, registered in Scotland,
            with registration number SC005336.
          </p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
        at     org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
    at      org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
    at     org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:64)
    at     org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:40)
    at     org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:45)
    at testscribe.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

I think this url "https://webapps.ph.ed.ac.uk/qtiworks-dev2/lti/domainlaunch" is invalid, but I don't know what I should use.